# Android first step?

Tags: android

Может покажусь ТП, но инфа в сети либа устарела, либо я не понимаю ничего. Запускаю Android Studio. Все тормозит, создаю проект. Пытаюсь запустить - получаю

```
C:\Users\Des\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

пытаюсь скачать - получаю

ось - win7 x64

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

есть релевантные ссылки для новичков?

UPD

кто-то пишет что мона эклипсе писать
пытаюсь загрузить adt
получаю

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

---

как понимаю самая трабла в том что проц AMD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы попытались запустить ваше приложение на эмуляторе Nexus 5 с архитектурой х86. Для работы этой архитектуры вам (почему-то) требуется установить Intel HAXM, для которого требуется поддержка процессором VT-x технологии. Ваш проц ее не поддерживает(или она выключена в BIOS).
Вывод: Запускайте на реальном устройстве, создайте эмулятор с архитектурой ARM, или используйте альтернативный эмулятор.(Genymotion)

Answer (score 2):

VT-x - это железная технология, которая поддерживается практически всеми современными настольными процессорами intel.
Обычно включается в bios-е. 
[image: Пример для pheonix bios]

Answer (score 1):

HAXM не встанет на процессор от AMD и на урезанные ноутбучные версии процессоров типа celeron. Если у вас Intel то можно попробовать включить в биос, мне удалось таким образом запустить на десктопном селероне.
Если проц АМД то сразу идите качайте Genymotion - он вполне юзабельный и бесплатный.

Но налучшим решением безусловно будет реальное устройство т.к. много вещей невозможно протестировать не симуляторе в принципе, или они работают некорректно.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать Intel HAXM, это небольшое приложение-драйвер для запуска x86 эмулятора. По идее можно попробовать установить его и на процессоры AMD, но только на неурезанную версию (линейки 83xx и 97xx), но тут как повезет с остальным железом.
Если вы не стали счастливым обладателем такого процессора, то всегда можно развернуть Android на VirtualBox.